# c# date/time format

Tags: c#, .net

can anyone help me with the formatting of the following?

```
if(system.datetime.now > 20:00:00 AND < 23:59:59)
    NewDateTime = (system.datetime.now + 1 day) + time as 00:01:00
```

ie if the sysdate meets the criteria, make NewDateTime = Sysdate + 1 day, with the time as 00:01:00

thanks

Comment: You are not doing any formatting here at all - and this is not something that will compile either.

Comment: Is this just pseudo code? If not then your syntax is all wrong. `AND` instead of `&&`, incorrect formats for time limits etc.

Comment: Its part of a caml query Ive to amend - I know it wont compile, I was just laying it out in plain(ish) english - ok then its not the formatting I need help with but the syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be dealing with *formatting* at all here. I suspect you want something like:

```
TimeSpan earliest = new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0);
TimeSpan latest = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan currentTime = now.TimeOfDay;

if (currentTime > earliest && currentTime < latest)
{
    DateTime newDateTime = now.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(1);
}
```

One important point here is that I'm only taking `DateTime.Now` *once*, rather than every time we're interested in "the current time". That leads to better consistency.

I'd also question your "latest" part - do you *really* want the behaviour to be different at 23:59:59.5? Don't you *really* mean "any time after 8pm"? And possibly that should be inclusive, too? That would lead to:

```
// Probably make this a static readonly field
TimeSpan earliest = new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0); 

DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan currentTime = now.TimeOfDay;
if (currentTime >= earliest)
{
    DateTime newDateTime = now.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(1);
}
```

Comment: Bah, beat by The Skeet in like 20 seconds! Rep hog! And I bought your book as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime newDateTime;
if (now.Hours >= 20)
{
   newDateTime = now.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(1);
}
```

Comment: will the condition (now.Hours > 8) work if the hour is 8:30:00 for example (it should return true)?

Comment: Good point, amended to `now.Hours >= 20` . At 20:30, `now.Hours` will be 20.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly this is what I think you want:

```
CurrentTime=DateTime.Now; 
if(CurrentTime.GetHour()>19)
{
    NewDateTime=CurrentTime.AddDays(1);
    NewDateTime.SetHour(1);
    NewDateTime.SetMinute(0);
    NewDateTime.SetSecond(0);
}
```

I think you can do that - if not you can calculate the time based on the current time

```
NewDateTime.AddHours(-CurrentTime.Hour-1)
NewDateTime.AddMinutes(-CurrentTime.Minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid in many aspects:

```
if(system.datetime.now > 20:00:00 AND < 23:59:59)
```

In C#, there is no "between" operator, so you need two comparisons plus the `AND`:

```
if(system.datetime.now > 20:00:00 AND system.datetime.now < 23:59:59)
```

It is `&&` (for `or`, it is `||`)

```
if(system.datetime.now > 20:00:00 && system.datetime.now < 23:59:59)
```

Note that `&&` and `||` have short-circuit behaviour, that is, if the left operand of `&&` if `false`, the right operand is not evaluated. Same for `||`, except that if the left hand operand is `true`, the right hand operand is not evaluated.

C# does not have time literals. Now it depends on what exactly you want to compare. Do you intend to see whether it is 20 o'clock already? Then do (note that `DateTime.Now` also contains today's date, `DateTime.Today` is the beginning of the current day):

```
if(system.datetime.now > system.datetime.today.addHours (20)
    && system.datetime.now < system.datetime.today.addDays (1))
```

C# source code is case sensitive, so

```
if(System.DateTime.Now > System.Datetime.Today.AddHours (20)
    && System.DateTime.Now < System.DateTime.Today.AddDays (1))
```

You could also work with `TimeSpan`s, which comes in handy when you also want to specify minutes and seconds (assume 20:15 for example):

```
if(System.DateTime.Now > System.Datetime.Today.Add (new TimeSpan(20,15,0))
    && System.DateTime.Now < System.DateTime.Today.AddDays (1))
```

I'd advise to use a named value, though:

```
var tomorrow = System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
var quincyTime = today.Add (new TimeSpan (20,15,0));

if(System.DateTime.Now > quincyTime && System.DateTime.Now < tomorrow)
```

Further, which is important, `Now` gives you (roughly) the moment when you call it. So if you have multiple invocations of `Now`, store it so it doesn't change throughout the execution of your function:

```
var now        = System.DateTime.Now;
var today      = System.DateTime.Today;
var quincyTime = today.Add (new TimeSpan (20,15,0));
var tomorrow   = today.AddDays(1);

if(now > quincyTime && now < tomorrow)
```

The observing reader might recognize that not even `Today` might be save if this program runs in a nuclear power plant at midnight. There is cure:

```
var now        = System.DateTime.Now;
var today      = now.Date;
```

Also note that the if-body is either a single statement, e.g.

```
if(now > quincyTime && now < tomorrow)
    ; // empty statement

if(now > quincyTime && now < tomorrow)
    foobar();
```

or a whole "block":

```
if(now > quincyTime && now < tomorrow)
{
} // empty block


if(now > quincyTime && now < tomorrow)
{
    foobar();
    frob();
}
```

Btw, if you meant "at least"/"at max" instead of "later"/"sooner", use `<=` and `>=`:

```
if(now >= quincyTime && now <= tomorrow) {...}
```